# Atlassian aui single select isn't rendered in velocity template

Tags: java, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I'm trying to add single select to my Jira Plugin according to [aui documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/aui/latest/docs/single-select.html) 
I added dependency to plugin.xml:

```
<dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:aui-select</dependency>
```

And added related code to velocity template:

```
    <form class="aui" action="" id="sync-single-select-container-form">
        <label for="sync-product-single-select">Choose your product synchronously:</label>
        <p>
            <aui-select name="product" id="sync-product-single-select">
                <option>Hipchat</option>
                <option>JIRA</option>
                <option>Confluence</option>
                <option>Stash</option>
                <option>FeCru</option>
            </aui-select>
        </p>
    </form>
```

but in html I just get list of options, not drop-down list: http://prntscr.com/5sjhgw
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Did you import the aui-select

```
#requireResource("com.atlassian.auiplugin:aui-select")
```

Through this code, put this at the top of vm file

Comment: Thank you! I tried to find my mistake for about 10h. Your answer really changed my life.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was found. It works with

```
<select>
```

and

```
new AJS.SingleSelect()
```

in js file.

Comment: Where is `<select>` and `new AJS.SingleSelect()` used?

Comment: @EricMajerus I included `<select id="mySelectId">` in my velocity template. I then just added `<script>
new AJS.SingleSelect({
 element: $("#mySelectId")
 });
</script>` beneath which worked

Answer (score 0):

I guess because "Single select" is a part of EXPERIMENTAL API.

You can try dropdown from the [Forms sample](https://docs.atlassian.com/aui/latest/docs/forms.html):

```
<form class="aui">
    <div class="field-group">
        <label for="select-example">Dropdown</label>
        <select class="select" id="select-example" name="select-example">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <optgroup label="Group 1">
                <option>Option one</option>
                <option>Option two</option>
            </optgroup>
            <option>Option 3</option>
            <option>Option 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```